# Можно ли сохранить в Shared Preferences 100 и более ключей со значениями?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Я знаю что можно воспользоваться SQLITE. Но я просто хочу узнать можно ли это сделать

Comment: ну это же так легко тестом определить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все данные хранятся в `xml` файле и архитектурно нет никаких ограничений на количество пар ключ-значение, однако нужно понимать, что этот файл может занимать очень много места при большом количестве пар, что может негативно влиять на процесс использования Вашего приложения.